Failed to load PDF File - react PDF
I am trying to view a pdf file the I am gonna get from an API, the API will return a pdf file, and then i am gonna process it as a blob so that the user can download it after viewing it, but I am having a problem with loading it using react-pdf, and I don't know why.
Here is the code:
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SchoolsContext, WorksheetContext } from 'context/Context';
import { pdfjs, Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/TextLayer.css';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
  'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.mjs',
  import.meta.url
).toString();

const WorksheetViewer = () => {
  const { worksheet, setWorksheet } = useContext(WorksheetContext);
  const { school } = useContext(SchoolsContext);
  const [PDF, setPDF] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handlePdfDownload = () => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = PDF;
    link.download = 'worksheet.pdf';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  };

  const setQuestions = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const questions = Object.entries(
          worksheet?.selections?.learningObjectives || {}
        ).reduce((acc, [id, LO]) => {
          const selectedQuestions = [];
          const indices = new Set();
          const questionsNumber = LO?.questions?.length || 0;
          let num = parseInt(LO?.selectedQuestions, 10);

          while (num > 0) {
            const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionsNumber);
            if (!indices.has(randomIndex)) {
              indices.add(randomIndex);
              selectedQuestions.push({
                ...LO?.questions[randomIndex],
                type: 1,
                index: randomIndex
              });
              num--;
            }
          }

          acc[id] = selectedQuestions;
          return acc;
        }, {});

        const newWorksheet = {
          ...worksheet,
          selections: {
            ...worksheet?.selections,
            questions
          },
          settings: { ...worksheet?.settings, school: school }
        };

        setWorksheet(newWorksheet);
        resolve(newWorksheet);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  };

  const handleWorksheetGeneration = async () => {
    const needToGetQuestion = Object.entries(
      worksheet?.selections?.learningObjectives || {}
    ).some(([id, LO]) => {
      const questions = worksheet?.selections?.questions?.[id] || [];
      return parseInt(LO?.selectedQuestions, 10) !== questions.length;
    });

    console.log('Need to get questions:', needToGetQuestion);
    console.log('Worksheet:', worksheet);

    if (needToGetQuestion) {
      try {
        const newWorksheet = await setQuestions();
        await requestWorksheet(newWorksheet);
      } catch (error) {
        setError('Failed to set questions.', error);
      }
    } else {
      await requestWorksheet(worksheet);
    }
  };

  const requestWorksheet = async worksheet => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/generate-worksheet', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ worksheet })
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }

      const blob = await response.blob();
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      setPDF(url);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('There was an error with the fetch operation:', error);
      setError('Failed to download the PDF.', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleWorksheetGeneration();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (PDF) {
      console.log('PDF successfully set:', PDF);
    }
  }, [PDF]);

  return (
    <>
      {error && <p>Error: {error}</p>}
      {PDF ? (
        <>
          <Document
            file={{ url: PDF }}
            onLoadError={error => {
              console.error('Error loading document:', error);
              setError('Error loading document');
            }}
          >
            <Page pageNumber={1} />
          </Document>
          <Button onClick={handlePdfDownload}>Download PDF</Button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default WorksheetViewer;

I read about PDFJS worker and tried to view other issues and questions but non of them help me

Any error  message in the devtools' console?

try with link.href = "data:application/pdf," + encodeURIComponent(PDF);

My problem is not with downloading it, my problem is with viewing the pdf  in the website using react-pdf, @mmm

Warning: Error: Setting up fake worker failed: "Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:3334/static/media/pdf.worker.min.dc35d2044cb3be560157.mjs".
This is an error that I can get in the console, @CaioCosta

I guess my problem is the pdfjs worker, but I don't know what cause the problem

are you sure you can read a existing pdf with react-pdf ? in the documentation I only see examples where pdf is generated. and I dont see "file" argument for "Document" : https://react-pdf.org/components#document
